# Lowercase filename-string in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lowercase, analyzer

I have two files:

```
1) test_Report_test.pdf 
2) test2_report.pdf
```

When I search for "report" I will only find the second file, yet I also want the first one to be found. How do I need to adapt the Analyzer/Tokenizer in Elasticsearch to lowercase the filename-string, not the searchstring?

My Python-Code to search for the filename:

```
resFilename = es.search(index=j,ignore=[404], body={
            "size": 500,  
            "query": {  
                "bool": {  
                    "should": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": ["file.filename"],  
                            "boost": 10,
                            "query": ("*" + Such_Str + "*") or ("*" + Such_Str) or (Such_Str + "*"),  # query-string always in wildcards
                            "minimum_should_match": "75%", 
                            "default_operator": "OR"}  
                    }
                }
            }
})
```

Comment: How is `file.filename` index? Is it indexed as a text in which case it will be analyzed so "report" or "Report" should return both values. If its indexed as keyword then "report" is dfferent from "Report".

Comment: You are right! The type was set to "keyword". Now it is changed to: **"file": { properties": { "filename": { type": "text", "store": true }}}** Still does not work, although I restarted Elasticseach and the FS-Crawler....

Comment: Your complete mapping doesn't look like this : `{"j":{"mappings":{"properties":{"file":{"properties":{"filename":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}}}` ?

Comment: No, the complete one is: `{ "mappings": {"properties": { "file": { "properties": {  "filename": {   "type": "keyword",  "store": true }}}}}}` This is created by Default by the FS-Crawler